# Como alterar a conjunção entre os autores do modelo hepthesis no Overleaf?

Tags: latex

Salve pessoal.
Escrevi a minha dissertação utilizando o template/classe "[hepthesis](http://repositorios.cpai.unb.br/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/hepthesis/hepthesis.pdf)" no Overleaf. O modelo é em inglês. Logo, na escrita inicial eu não me preocupei com os floreios necessários.
Porém agora eu estou com uns pequenos impasses para passar partes do texto para português.

**Problema 1**: As minhas referências todas estão usando a conjunção `and` entre os autores. 
Autor1 `and` Autor2....

Eu quero alterar para português. Portanto, seria:
Ziviani `e` Alves...

**Problema 2**: Alguns títulos insistem em ficar em inglês, como Declaration, Acknowledgments, Preface, Nomenclature etc. Eu já usei o 
`\selectlanguage{brazilian}`, mas não tive muito sucesso.

A saber, a classe hepthesis possui dois arquivos: thesis.cls e thesis.sty. Em nenhum deles há indicações de como posso fazer as alterações nas referências.
E os pacotes básicos que estou utilizando são:

```
\documentclass[bind,a4paper]{thesis}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não estou muito seguro mas vê se isto ajuda

1) No teu exemplo estás a usar `\documentclass[bind,a4paper]{thesis}` esperava `hepthesis`

2) Para os bibtex vê se `\usepackage[...Lingua...]{babelbib}` ajuda.

3) Normalmente para tratar dos títulos e afins,internamente o babel define
uma macro para renomear à lingua (Exemplo     `\def\chaptername{Cap\'{\i}tulo}`) . Um tentativa seria fazeres algo análogo
para os elementos em falta.

Answer (score 0):

Marcos Alves,

tive o mesmo problema que você e utilizei este comando abaixo para substituir o "and" por "e":

```
\iflanguage{brazil}{}{ 
        \renewcommand{\HAR@and@agsm}{\&}
        \renewcommand{\HAR@and@dcu}{e}
        \renewcommand{\HAR@and@apsr}{e}
    }
```